# Error on checkout page while adding product to cart

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, magento2.3

I am using a custom module, where I want to redirect to checkout page once a product is adding to cart. For this I have created an event on frontend **"checkout_cart_add_product_complete"**.

For simple product its working fine. But where I am adding a configurable product it will redirect to checkout page with attribute data so(Check in last for URL reference), I am getting an error of **noroute** on checkout.

Here is my Observer code:

```
   $observer->getRequest()->setParam('return_url', $this->_url->getUrl('checkout'));
```

> My error on checkout page because url become like:-
>   **www.yourDomain.com/checkout/#size=173&color=53**

Note: Using **Magento 2.3**

Comment: please edit the question with the error

Comment: getting noroute error on checkout. Because my URL become like www.yourDomain.com/checkout/#size=173&color=53 so getting noroute error. 
It should be www.yourDomain.com/checkout/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code if it helps:

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[modulename]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class [YourClass] implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory
     */
    private $responseFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    private $url;

    public function __construct(
        ......
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        ......
    ) {
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        //your custom code
        $redirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('checkout/index/index');
        $this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($redirectionUrl)->sendResponse();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working. Product only add to cart. Not redirect to checkout.

Comment: $observer->getRequest()->setParam('return_url', $this->_url->getUrl('checkout'));
This works but same issue in url.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $requst = $observer->getRequest();
 $params = $requst ->getParams();
 foreach($params as $key => $value) {   
   unset($params[$key]);           
 }
 $request->setParam('return_url', $this->_url->getUrl('checkout'));
```

Comment: Not working. A product can not be adding to cart.

Answer (score 0):

instead of create observer try to override following controller.
Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add

In Add.php you will find code for redirect on cart page. Change this code with following code

```
$baseUrl = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getBaseUrl();

return $this->goBack($baseUrl.'checkout', $product);
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi aniket you can try this

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface
 */
protected $redirect;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect
) {
    $this->redirect = $redirect;
}


public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
        $this->redirect->redirect($controller->getResponse(), 'checkout/index/index');
OR
$controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This magento 2.3 version issue. If you try with normal checkout and enable option redirect to checkout after product add to cart Enable you will get same error.

To sort Issue:
 app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/web/js/catalog-add-to-cart.js

```
if (eventData.redirectParameters.length > 0) {
                        parameters = res.backUrl.split('#');
                        //parameters.push(eventData.redirectParameters.join('&'));
                        res.backUrl = parameters.join('#');
                    }
```

comment Previous Line.